# Joomla 2.5: Migration to new server, but all links keep redirecting back to old server

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

Migrated a Joomla 2.5 site to a new server with different domain. Homepage is showing up with correct url address. When hovering on links, it shows the correct address, but when clicked on any navigation links, I get redirected to old server domain. AceSEF is installed on the site, so I disabled it. And it's still not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the @live_site parameter in the configuration.php file and check the .htaccess file if you have one.

Also try clearing the cache.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't live site. Seemed to be htaccess and also cleared cache.